# What is this scrolling speed effect called and how to achieve it?

Tags: java, css, google-chrome, scroll

I'm learning CSS and I've been looking into parallax effect because it's awesome @.@ ... but I don't like how most of them scroll. I really want to figure out how to achieve a nice smooth scrolling like on [this website](https://www.adamunderwear.com/). I've been trying to figure out what it's called. I think it's momentum scrolling? But for some reason, when trying to find more examples or tutorials on how to do it, all examples of "smooth" or "momentum" scrolling I found work just like regular jerky scrolling, at least for me on Chrome.
I was wondering if someone could nudge me in the right direction of where I could learn more about how to code this specifically for Chrome at least.
Thank you.

Comment: Parallax scrolling. There's tons of frameworks for this.

Comment: i know it's parallax scrolling ... I mean the actual movement of the frames ... in most parallax effects it's jerky, as in they only move when your mouse wheel moves and at constant speed.
On the website I referenced, the scrolling speed starts out slow, then picks up, then slows down after the scrolling has stopped.

Comment: this helped me : https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/practical-css-parallax/ googling 'kinetic scrolling' might also help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site uses CSS Transforms.

If you are familiar with parallax and that is not the question, then the effect you are noticing that differentiates this site from others with parallax is the transitional easing in (CSS Transitions).

So the state of the elements on the page are eased in gradually from a beginning state to an ending state.

More specifically you may want to look into CSS Transform Matrix : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/matrix.

Also for further research I highly recommend Sarah Drasner's book SVG Animations and also the book CSS Animations and Transitions for the Modern Web by Steven Bradley.

And for more inspiration look into "scrollytelling" and Shirley Wu from http://www.datasketch.es/. She is really into graceful scrollytelling and puts up amazing examples all the time.

Hope that helps!

Comment: i tried adding
`transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.235, 0.615, 0.185, 0.995);` to my
`.parallax__layer--base {

    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    z-index: 4;
  }` but it's still not easing in and out :(